# Having problems with website coding, centering a picture

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems with the following code.

```
<tbody>
<tr align="center">
<td>
<p align="right"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><strong>Processoren</strong>
<img src="images/IntelPentium4.jpg" align="middle" height="37" width="50"> </font></p>
</td>
<td>
<p align="right"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><strong>Moederborden
</strong> <img src="images/MB.jpg" align="middle" height="47" width="47"> </font></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
<td height="54" width="50%">
<p align="right"><strong><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Geheugen &nbsp;<img src="images/geh.gif" align="middle" height="47" width="50"></font></strong></p>
</td>
 <td height="54" width="50%">
  <p align="right"><strong><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Grafische kaarten <img src="images/56326.jpg" align="middle" height="50" width="50"></font></strong></p></td>
</tr>
<br><br><br>
</tbody><tbody>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"> <img src="images/gamepc1.png" width="140" > </td>
<td align="right"> <img src="images/gamepc2.jpg" width="120"> </td></tr>
</tbody><tr>
<td></td>
<td class="test11"><img src="images/annie2.png" width="140">
</td></tr>
<tbody>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"> <img src="images/gamepc3.png" width="120"> </td> 
<td align="right"> <img src="images/gamepc4.png" width="100"> </td> 
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjcpm.png)
Basicly, I can't figure out how to center the anime picture. Please dont ask me why there is random anyme on this webpage, but the owner of the store wanted me to do that. I've tried so many options to center the picture, they just work. Could someone try to take a look at it and help me out?

I tried centering it with css rules, also tried margin-left shit but I cant figure out why its not reaction on such code.

I've never worked with  and  before. I'm a first year student who had to make some websites for school that worked out pretty good. My friend asked me if I could fix some stuff for his work's owner's website. This website is designed like 10years ago. I already asked him if I couldn't just make a new one, but he insisted that I need to use this one.

Could someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: Arjen, Please use good formatting on your question, mainly indentation and tags on correct/good lines. In addition review your question since I think you have content missing (invisible inline html). And narrow the code down to a [mcve]

Comment: You are using outdated and deprecated HTML - don't use align tags in the HTML.   If you want to use inline CSS, you'll need to embed your code inside a `style` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `tbody` with the image of the anime you are using two `<td>`.

You can delete the first `<td></td>` and use `colspan="2"` for the other td, so you will only need one td. This td will take the full width. Now you can easily center the image.

```
<td colspan="2" class="test11" style="text-align:center;">
  <img src="images/annie2.png" width="140">
</td>
```

Result look like this (be aware, I have not included the sources of the images).

[image]

Comment: There is no `align:center` CSS property. I think you are thinking of the deprecated `align="center"` attribute

Comment: My bad, you are totally right. Align is wrong. Will edit it, thanks! @zgood